# Excel VBA ListBox Total in Currency Format

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

How I can put the total column value in currency (example $27265,28), searching I found the code .AddItem Format(Cell.Value, "$#,##0.00") but it didn't work, I need the **Listbox** column to be formatted as currency ("$#,##0.00).[image]

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub


Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Me.TextBox1 = Format(StrConv(Me.TextBox1, vbLowerCase))

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim p As Long
Me.ListBox1.Clear

For i = 2 To sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To Len(sh.Cells(i, 2))
p = Me.TextBox1.TextLength

If LCase(Mid(sh.Cells(i, 2), x, p)) = Me.TextBox1 And Me.TextBox1 <> "" Then
With Me.ListBox1

.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 2)

.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = sh.Cells(i, 3)

.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Cells(i, 4)

.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Cells(i, 5)

.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Cells(i, 6)

.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Cells(i, 7)

End With


End If

Next x

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Does `cstr(Format(cell.Value, "$#,##0.00"))` work?  I've tried your code and it works ok for me.

Comment: Btw You should insert a `Exit For` after `End With` and before `End If` to avoid possible multiple display of the same occurrence. @MarcMelo

Comment: I forgot to inform you that it is in the listbox, but thanks for your time to help me

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
sh.Columns("C").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"
```

as it's mentioned in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat

Comment: I forgot to inform you that it is in the listbox

Comment: Then `Format(sh.Cells(i, 3), "$#,##0.00")`